# PHP - include using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] gives permission denied although its 777?

Tags: php, include

I'm trying to get the root of my app in order to include files starting from it..
I use this

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/myfile.php'
```

It show this error:

```
Warning: include_once(/usr/local/apache/htdocs/includes/db.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: Permission denied .....etc
```

> Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '/usr/local/apache/htdocs/includes/myfile.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/usernamehere/public_html/includes/parentfile.php on line 14

but when use part of $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] (which equals '/home/username/public_html/parentfile.php') like this:

```
include_once '/home/username/public_html/includes/myfile.php';
```

It works correctly with no errors.

Is it a permission issue from server administrator side? Or I can solve it from mine?

Comment: Have you walked the directory path?

Comment: Didn't get it, what do you mean by "walked" ?

Comment: I.e. checked the permissions/ownership/grouup for /usr/, /usr/local/ ...

Comment: Yes I did, the folder 'includes' has 777 permission.

Comment: How about the ones before

Comment: you need to give 777 to that folder to whatever user apache runs under.

Comment: @JakeGould 100% agreed, though when troubleshooting permissions issues I like to open and then lock down as bugs & permissions are two separate concerns is why I recommended the 777 with the assumption to change it later.  No big deal though my thought train was in a different direction anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not work because it this:

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']  . '/includes/myfile.php';
```

That `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` refers to the absolute web server main document root for the web server itself. Not [per-user `public_html` web directories](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/public_html.html). Which is why this works:

```
include_once '/home/username/public_html/includes/myfile.php';
```

> Is it a permission issue from server administrator side? Or I can
>   solve it from mine?

1,000,000% no. This is simply an understanding of what path is what & why on a server.

Also, `777` permissions are horrible & a security risk. If the first think you believe needs to be done to solve an issue like this is to just go `chmod 777` you are not solving the problem & creating a security risk.

`777` means that 100% of anyone can read, write or execute that file. And that is just not needed for PHP running under Apache.

For a PHP file it can jet be `664` or `644` because PHP files do not need to be executed. They just need to be read by the file system & then parsed by the Apache PHP module.

That said, if you are trying to simplify the way that files are loaded, you should explicitly set a `$BASE_PATH` like this:

```
$BASE_PATH = '/home/username/public_html/';
```

And then set your `include_once` like this:

```
include_once $BASE_PATH  . 'includes/myfile.php';
```

Automatting the way file paths are set for installs just never works well. Best just to manually set a `$BASE_PATH` in a config file when you move code than deal with the headaches caused by PHP constants like `$_SERVER` not being consistent between installs, setups & configurations.

Comment: so I should always try ti get '/home/username/public_html/', do you have a good way to do it ?

Answer (score -1):

The document root is set in apache. If not configured right your doc root could be somewhere else.

That being said, you should look at map ownership. Apache runs under a set user. If your user does not have rights to the specific folder (ie user root, which is probably not your apache user) you won't have access.

The 777 isn't necessary for includes and is even not recommended for a folder which apache has access to. 776 should be the absolute maximum for rights.

Comment: yes, i get that sir. But that max is for upload folders. And it was to itterate on the fact that 777 is even worse. But thank you for your comment.